# Add extra fields to odoo many2many field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

I am trying to create a fine allocation functionality in hr.employee.This module inherits from `hr.employee`. The process is:

1. Click the Fine Allocation menu that opens a wizard. The wizard has a many2many relation field called employee_ids related to hr.employee. This should enable you to select batch employees and allocate fines together.

2.There being a field with name `fine_amount`, allocate individual fines for employees in each of the lines and then allocate fines by click of a button.

My question is, how do I extend this many2many field with the fine_amount field?

If I extend the hr.employee form with this field, it is not among the selected fields in the many2many lines.

My code looks like this

```
class FineAllocation(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'fine.allocation'
_description = 'Fine Allocation'

@api.model
def action_allocate_fine(self):
    pass

employee_ids = fields.Many2many('hr.employee','hr_employee_group_rel', 'deductions_id' 'Employees')
fine_amount = fields.Float(string='Fine Amount')
```

And this is for the wizard record view

```
<record id="employee_fine_allocation_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Employee Fine Allocation Form</field>
        <field name="model">fine.allocation</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Employee Fine Allocation">
                <group>
                    <span colspan="4" nolabel="1">This wizard will allocate fines for all selected employee(s) equalling the input fine amount.</span>
                </group>

                <group colspan="4">
                    <separator string="Employees" colspan="4" />
                    <newline />
                    <field name="employee_ids" nolabel="1" />
                </group>

                <footer>
                    <button name="action_allocate_fine" string="Allocate Fines" type="object" class="btn-primary" />
                    <button string="Cancel" class="btn-secondary" special="cancel" />
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: You need a One2many field for this kind of behavior, create a new model to link between your Wizard and the employee model. And the new model will have three field m2o for wizard, m2o for employee,  fine_amount

Comment: Thank you @CharifDZ, let me try that.

Comment: You want to specify fine amount for each employee?

Comment: Yes, like the amount can be different for an employee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the many2many field shows the default view.

> When a view is requested by (model, type), the view matching the model and the type, with the lowest priority will be returned (it is the default view).

To show the field in the many2many list you can extend the default view or define your view, try one of the followings:

1. Extend the default tree view `hr.view_employee_tree`:

   ```
    <record id="view_employee_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hr.employee.tree</field>
        <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <field name="fine_amount"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
   ```
2. Define a new tree view and force the many2many field to show it:

   ```
    <record id="view_employee_tree_allocate_fine" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">hr.employee.tree.allocate.fine</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Employees" decoration-bf="message_needaction==True">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="work_phone" class="o_force_ltr"/>
            <field name="work_email"/>
            <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company"/>
            <field name="department_id"/>
            <field name="job_id"/>
            <field name="parent_id"/>
            <field name="coach_id" invisible="1"/>
            <field name="message_needaction" invisible="1"/>

            <field name="fine_amount"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
    </record>
   ```

   To force the many2many field to show a specific view, pass `tree_view_ref` in context:

   ```
   <field name="employee_ids" nolabel="1" context="{'tree_view_ref': 'module_name.view_employee_tree_allocate_fine'}"/>
   ```
3. Define the tree view in place:

   ```
    <field name="employee_ids">
        <tree editable="bottom">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="work_phone" class="o_force_ltr"/>
            <field name="work_email"/>
            <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company"/>
            <field name="department_id"/>
            <field name="job_id"/>
            <field name="parent_id"/>
            <field name="coach_id" invisible="1"/>
            <field name="message_needaction" invisible="1"/>

            <field name="fine_amount"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
   ```

***Edit:***

Set `editable` option to `bottom` when defining tree view in place.

***Edit2:***

With the following definition:

```
employee_ids = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', 'hr_employee_rel', 'payslip_id', 'Employees')
```

Odoo will try to create records and setting the value of `column2` (It is not passed explicitly in the example above ) to `Employees` which will raise the following error:

```
the “employees” column of the “hr_employee_rel” relationship does not exist
LINE 2: ...   INSERT INTO hr_employee_rel (payslip_id, Employees)...
```

`employee_id` is missing if you compare it to [employee_ids](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/hr_payroll/wizard/hr_payroll_payslips_by_employees.py#L12) in `hr_payroll` wizard model.

In your question, you can see that there is no comma between `deductions_id` and `Employees`, Python will concatenate the two strings and you will end with `column1` set to `deductions_idEmployees`. Odoo should raise the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: ERROR: the column « deductions_idemployees » of the relation « hr_employee_group_rel » does not exist
LINE 2: ... INSERT INTO hr_employee_group_rel (deductions ...
```

You could avoid that error if you passed `Employees` as the string attribute, the second column (column2 attribute) should be generated automatically as it is an optional. You can try the following definition:

```
employee_ids = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', 'hr_employee_fine_allocation_rel', 'payslip_id', string='Employees')
```

The attributes `relation`, `column1` and `column2` are optional. If not given, names are automatically generated from model names.

If you do not need to set them explicitly, the field declaration can be reduced to:

```
employee_ids = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', string='Employees')
```

Comment: Thank you @Kenly, I have learnt alot from this. While these choices works fine, i needed the `fine_amount`  field to be editable from the tree view. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome, check my edit on how to add the editable option

Comment: Woah number 3 actually works as expected, though am getting a relational error, could you help me understand the relations that should go into the many2many field, on looking on the same code in odoo the many field is defined as `employee_ids=fields.Many2many('hr.employee','hr_employee_rel','payslip_id','Employees')

Comment: This is the actual error psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "employees" does not exist
LINE 2:                 INSERT INTO Employees (fine_id, hr_employee_...
                                    ^

Comment: Odoo will try to use `Employees` as a column to create records, Check my edit.

Comment: Did you use another declaration (not mentioned above)  when you got that error?

Comment: Thank you @Kenly, with the new edit everything worked fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Ok try this, In python side:

```py
class FineAllocation(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'fine.allocation'
    _description = 'Fine Allocation'
    
    # Use one two many field because you need to information an employee and fine amount
    employee_allocation_ids = fields.One2many('fine.allocation.amount', 'Employees allocations')
    
    def action_allocate_fine(self):
        for rec in self.employee_allocation_ids:
            for rec in self.employee_allocation_ids:
               vals = {
                 'deduction_id': 1,
                 'computation': 'fixed',
                 'fixed': rec.fine_amount,
                 'employee_id': rec.employee_id.id,
               }
               self.env['ke.deductions'].sudo().create(vals)
    

# create the model that will hold the two information and link them to the wizard 
class FineAllocationAmount(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'fine.allocation.amount'
    _description = 'Fine Allocation'
    
    fine_allocation_id = fields.Many2one('fine.allocation')
    
    employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', 'Employee', required=True)
    fine_amount = fields.Float('Fine amount')
```

In your Form view:

```xml
<record id="employee_fine_allocation_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Employee Fine Allocation Form</field>
        <field name="model">fine.allocation</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Employee Fine Allocation">
                <group>
                    <span colspan="4" nolabel="1">This wizard will allocate fines for all selected employee(s) equalling the input fine amount.</span>
                </group>

                <group colspan="4">
                    <separator string="Employees" colspan="4" />
                    <newline />
                    <field name="employee_allocation_ids" nolabel="1" >
                         <!-- Use tree view to fill the information no need to open anather popup -->
                        <tree editable="bottom">
                          <field name="employee_id"/>
                          <field name="fine_amount"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </group>

                <footer>
                    <button name="action_allocate_fine" string="Allocate Fines" type="object" class="btn-primary" />
                    <button string="Cancel" class="btn-secondary" special="cancel" />
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you @Charif Dz, this might not be what i really wanted but it served the purpose. I appreciate it

Comment: Thanks @Eric I am glad I helped you, sorry I thought this is what you need, I didn't notice the part where you say that this field exists in hr.employee model